# Firefox PostBacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone have an idea why these buttons work in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox? Also, my dropdowns which I use to filter databound controls aren't working either...must be something to do with postbacks. How can I fix this? Many thanks for your help!

```
<asp:Button CssClass="button_style" ID="LinkButtonDetails" runat="server" Text="DETAILS" PostBackUrl='<%# GenerateLinkDetails(Eval("CompanyID"), Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
<asp:Button CssClass="button_style" ID="LinkButtonTagCloud" runat="server" Text="TAG CLOUD" PostBackUrl='<%# GenerateLinkCloud(Eval("CompanyID"), Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
```

Rendered HTML Markup:

```
<input type="submit" name="Gridview1$ctl02$LinkButtonTagCloud" 
       value="TAG CLOUD" 
       onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
               WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Gridview1$ctl02$LinkButtonTagCloud&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;displaycloud.aspx?guid=b6b98ee2-fadc-4624-95e5-eacf5f84eb73&amp;name=Dave&amp;role=Admin&amp;member=27&amp;company=17&amp;proje­ct=BIS Tests&amp;proj_id=9&quot;, false, false))" 
       id="Gridview1_ctl02_LinkButtonTagCloud" class="button_style" />
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML instead of the asp.net markup.

Comment: <input type="submit" name="Gridview1$ctl02$LinkButtonTagCloud" value="TAG CLOUD" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Gridview1$ctl02$LinkButtonTagCloud&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;displaycloud.aspx?guid=b6b98ee2-fadc-4624-95e5-eacf5f84eb73&amp;name=Dave&amp;role=Admin&amp;member=27&amp;company=17&amp;project=BIS Tests&amp;proj_id=9&quot;, false, false))" id="Gridview1_ctl02_LinkButtonTagCloud" class="button_style" />

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using `PostBackUrl`since it generates a HTTP-POST request and considering that you are trying to format your url like this

```
displaycloud.aspx?guid=b6b98ee2-fadc-4624-95e5-eacf5f84eb73&amp
```

I take it you are trying to do a HTTP-GET. So, you can just use a html button (not submit button) to do the redirection.

```
<input style="button_style" type="button" ID="LinkButtonDetails" runat="server" value="DETAILS" 
onclick='<%# GenerateLinkDetails(Eval("CompanyID"), Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
```